# Image not loading while url is retrieved correctly as3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, parsing, air

I am working with an app that first gets an xml feed from deviant-art and extract a url of image form that then shows it in a loader but when i trace it it shows the url retrieved but loader is not showing the image. ihave only written the neccassary code

```
var contentLoader:Loader = new Loader();
contentLoader.x = 10;
contentLoader.y = 100;
contentLoader.width = 280;
contentLoader.height = 260;
addChild(contentLoader);


function requestCompleted(e:Event):void
{
    var imageData:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
    var media:Namespace = imageData.namespace('media');
    trace(imageData.channel.item[0].media::content.@url);
    var image:URLRequest = new URLRequest(imageData.channel.item[0].media::content.@url);
    contentLoader.load(image);
}
```

it shows the URL in the output window because of trace statement but not showing it in loader

Comment: Would be useful to listen for the events listed at the bottom of this section: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#load%28%29  Remember to add the listeners to the `contentLoaderInfo` property of the loader

Comment: Specifically IOError, securtityError, progress, and complete will help you debug

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy and paste the URL from trace statement in your browser after clearing the cache and see if it works. The URL could be valid but it is possible that the image itself is missing

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a event listener so that contentLoader can listen

```
contentLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaderComplete);
private function onLoaderComplete():void
{
    contentLoader.load(image);
}
```

urlRequest should take some time to load so add this complete event and in the method load the image in loader and make the image variable as Global.